# How to enable tinyMCE rich text editor for post Comments in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I would love to kinda replicate WordPress post/page text editor (Admin panel) in comments section. That's how site users will be able to format text easily. A good example of what I actually need can be found here at StackOverflow when someone is about to Ask Question.

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/wordpress-tinymce_editor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TinyMCEComment WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymcecomments/) could help you out. It uses the internal TinyMCE editor (bundled in WordPress 2.0 and up).

Comment: …but doesn't work with the current 3.x versions of Wordpress.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/guahanweb-ajax-comments-with-wysiwyg-support/ Try this

Answer (score 7):

In your functions.php, add the following snippet:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'tinymce_comment_4265340' );
function tinymce_comment_4265340 ( $args ) {
    ob_start();
    wp_editor( '', 'comment', array('tinymce') );
    $args['comment_field'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $args;
}
```

It's working on WordPress 3.5 and Twenty Twelve theme.

Comment: With WP 3.5.x, add this code, there is some jquery error:

Error: TypeError: e is undefined
Source File: /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3
Line: 2

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.revood.com/blog/adding-visual-editor-to-wordpress-comments-box-part-2/) tutorial. It worked for me. The above answer might add TinyMCE to the reply section. The tutorial shows how to fix that.